# pip install selenium ERROR python 3.7 Windows 10

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.7

I downloaded Python 3.7 just now. Now I'm trying to install the selenium module. I am able to run python in my command prompt. But, when I type:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

or

```
pip install selenium
```

I get a syntax error.

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pip install -U selenium
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install -U selenium
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm thinking it's a bug with the new Python version, but not sure if anybody can tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: I guess you are typing into Python shell

Comment: Exit from Python shell and type into terminal.

Comment: type in cmd prompt, not python shell, have you already install pip in your windows? if not first you need to install then run your command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are typing into `Python shell`. 
To leave the interactive shell and go back to the console (the system shell), press `Ctrl-Z` and then Enter on Windows, or Ctrl-D on OS X or Linux. Alternatively, you could also run the python command `exit()`.

 Then type into *Command line Interface*.
By the way I believe you need to install using `pip3` rather than `pip`, since you are using python3.X.
So command would be

```
pip3 install -U selenium
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
python -m pip install selenium --user
```

pip defaults to installing Python packages to a system directory (such as `/usr/local/lib/python3.4`). This requires root access.

`--user` makes pip install packages in your home directory instead, which doesn't require any special privileges.

Comment: Hello Furkan. Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful for all readers if you explain your answer a bit. Just providing a code snippet can be helpful and in rare cases it's enough. But here I miss an explanation why this should work and why the OP has problems with his approach.

Answer (score 0):

You are typing the command in python shell.
Use quit() command to exit out of it and then run the pip command again
You can tell the difference by the sign in the front.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing error with the lines:

```
>>> pip install -U selenium
```

and

```
>>> pip install selenium
```

because you have issued those commands within the *Python Shell*.

Ideally, you should issue the commands from the *Command Line Interface* as:

```
>pip install -U selenium
```

Incase `pip` requires upgradation, you need to execute the following command from the *Command Prompt*:

```
>python -m pip install -U pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Try runnig cmd as administrator and it will.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install it from the command line.
Go to Python folder under the below location.

```
cd C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\{python version}\Scripts

pip install selenium
```

Comment: why user should go to that location? it will be already under environment variables, the issue here is user is trying in python shell instead of command line.

Comment: issue is correct but not sure if he added it in env variables, so easy way to move to location and run.

Comment: If the environment variables is the issue, the error would have been different.

Comment: for windows env you need to move to location for pip, for shell its acceptable

Comment: I get a subprocess error with nowhere to go tried pip,pip3 upgraded, cleaned cache and nothing , i had similar issues on mac thought win would do but it don't just wonder if they messed it up